# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE unknown number of columns

Tags: mysql, csv

I am very confused about `LOAD DATA INFILE`

after searching SO and google I have found no help on what I am attempting to do. 
I want to create a new table, and load the contents of a csv file. The csv files first row is the column names I want.

Or if that cannot be done, how can I load the file without knowing how many columns exist?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (... unknown number of columns ...);
```

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
  INTO TABLE t1`?

Comment: That will only work assuming the table has the correct number of columns to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a tool other than mysql to load csvs without a predetermined schema.

Comment: thats what I feared.. can you suggest any (hopefully _free_) good ones?

Comment: I don't know of any off hand, it would be pretty simple to code one up though.  Do you know any scripting languages?

Comment: Ok well I just solved my own problem . I am working with a rather large export from another program. The export only allows CSV exports, however it is outputting a invalid file. (problems escaping characters) - I did find the main mdf file .. so now i'm working on hacking into that. :)